# int test (unsigned int i = -1); why does the compiler not generate a warning?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Unsigned int can not be negative by default. The compiler generates a warning.
That's ok. 
But it is not clear for me why it does not generate a warning when I do the same thing in a function with a negative default value.

```
unsigned int test(unsigned int i = -1) { return i;} // no warnings! Why?

int main()
{
   unsigned int i = -1;        // warning warning C4245 (ok!)
   unsigned int j = test();    // no warnings!  Why?     
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree that your compiler ought to warn you of the default argument being negative. But compilers are not perfect. (And the standard permits the conversion of a negative integral value to an unsigned type.)

As for the warning on *calling* `test()`, how does the poor compiler *know* that `test()` will *always* return -1? The definition of the function might even be in a different compilation unit! (Granted it isn't in your case but compilers ought not to think that laterally when issuing warnings.)

If `test` were qualified with a `constexpr` then it would be a different matter and a compiler should be able to issue a warning.

Comment: I tested with G++ 5.1, `constexpr` doesn't seem to generate any warnings in this case.

Comment: Hum. Methinks it ought to. What about something like -1.1 which is actually UB?

Comment: @Bathsheba You're saying that `unsigned int i = -1.1` is Undefined Behavior?

Comment: It *certainly* is in C. Here's a question on exactly this from today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443556/what-is-the-behaviour-on-converting-a-negative-floating-point-value-into-an-unsi/36443650#comment60501023_36443650

Answer (score 2):

This conversion is [allowed without a cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aetzh118.aspx), as long as you are prepared to live with consequences:

> Objects of `unsigned` integral types can be converted to corresponding `signed` types. However, such a conversion can cause misinterpretation of data if the value of the unsigned object is outside the range representable by the signed type.

When you do a conversion from signed to unsigned and back, [the data will be preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800976/335858), though.

Comment: It is indeed allowed (interestingly though -1.0 is allowed too but a floating point value lower than that is UB), but my reading of the (good) question is why the compiler doesn't *warn* you.

Comment: When OP sets signed `-1` to `i`, the compiler knows that the data will be outside the range representable by `unsigned`, so it issues a warning. My only guess as to why C++ standard does not require a warning when a mis-interpretation *could* happen is that it guarantees identical bit representations, and the amount of potential harm from a no-op is limited.