# Out-of-range floating point to integer conversion breaks in VS2022 executable when linking VS2017 or VS2019 libraries

Tags: c, visual-c++, floating-point, sse, floating-point-conversion

I have a snippet of code that's present in a VS2017 static library. When linked in a 2017 executable, it works as expected. However, if linking into a 2022 executable, it breaks on the cast from double to uint64_t.

The `double` is below `-1.0` so the truncated value is outside the value-range of `uint64_t` and [ISO C doesn't define the behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443556/what-is-the-behaviour-on-converting-a-negative-floating-point-value-into-an-unsi), but MSVC does.

```
static uint64_t do_something_2(double f1)
{
    return (uint64_t)(f1 - 0.5);
}

uint32_t do_something(void)
{
    double f1 = -3406302.4613481420;
    uint32_t f2 = (uint32_t)do_something_2(f1);

    return f2;
}
```

When linking this into a 2022 executable, `f2` is `0xffffffff`, as if from `double` to `uint64_t` with AVX-512 [`vcvttsd2usi rax, xmm0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcvttsd2usi) which produces all-ones for out-of-range values.  (And then uint64_t to uint32_t truncation to get a 32-bit `0xffffffff` value)

However, if I re-compile the static library using VS2022, I get my expected value of `f2 = 4291560994` (0xffcc0622), as if  `(uint32_t)(uint64_t)double` did get modulo reduction of the integer `-3406302`.

(For values that also fit in `int64_t`, we can get this result portably and efficiently with `(uint64_t)(int64_t)double`, especially in x64 code or with x87+SSE3 `fisttp`.  But the question is why existing code written with `(uint64_t)double` doesn't compile the way I expected when mixing VS versions.)

---

When I compare the disassembly, I see the 2017-generated code just calls `__dtoul3` and nothing more.

The 2022 generated assembly is much more involved with many more calls.

Afterwards, I edited my 2017 makefile by adding /arch=IA32 to disable SSE2 and then recompiled. This resulted in the correct value being computed.

So it seems to be an issue with the SSE2 code generation in VS2017 vs VS2022. However, this blog post on Microsoft seems to suggest that 2022 and 2017 should be compatible: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/microsoft-visual-studio-2022-and-floating-point-to-integer-conversions/  It mentions changes to the default semantics for out-of-range FP to integer conversions to match AVX-512 instructions.

Only other things I'll add:

1. Tried compiling the library with 2019 and linking into the 2022 executable. Same issue as 2017, results in 0xFFFFFFF
2. The 2017 library linked into a 2017 executable does work.

Any idea why my findings seem to contradict Microsoft's blog post about floating point to integer conversions between 2017 and 2022?

Comment: As an update, I am using /fpcvt:BC which claims to be for compatibility with VS2017 (and also claims to be the default behavior for VS2022).

Comment: One more point for clarification: both the static library and executable are x86. Haven't tried this with x64.

Comment: @njuffa: The `double` value is negative, so its outside the value-range of `uint64_t`, and thus the behaviour is undefined.  ISO C has nothing to say here, it is up to the compiler (and their blog articles) to define the behaviour.  Unlike integer to narrower-integer conversions, you don't get modulo reduction to the value-range of an unsigned result. [What is the behaviour on converting a negative floating point value into an unsigned int?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36443556) (This one fooled me, too, until I looked at https://godbolt.org/z/vEqcsxE8z and saw GCC optimizing it to `return 0;`)

Comment: I edited the question with some of those background details.  I was also playing around with https://godbolt.org/z/scrvTxsY5 to see if MSVC would make efficient double to signed `int64_t` conversion code in 32-bit mode with SSE3 available (`fisttp`)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I ended up submitting a problem report to Microsoft through Visual Studio. For now doing the intermediate cast to (int64_t) solved the problem, but at this point I'm just curious as to why 2022 isn't compatible with 2017. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd assume 2022 changed the behaviour of `__dtoul3` to return the AVX-512 out-of-range value (UINT64_MAX).  Your 2017 is compiled to call it, so linking against a different library gives different variable.  And BTW, I forgot to say in my previous comment, no, unlike GCC, MSVC doesn't make efficient `fisttp` code for this even when it could (/arch:AVX implies SSE3 is available.)  Maybe an intrinsic could help.

Comment: @Robert Joseph Dacunto, please explain the functional goal of `do_something_2()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It's a greatly simplified snippet of code from some legacy embedded platform. The original goal is to take a 64-bit latitude or longitude and scale it down to 32-bit integer before transmitting to an external device.

It wasn't my code, but a teammate asked me about it after their tests were failing after switching from 2017 to 2022. The code is cross-platform between VxWorks 653 for target and native development with Visual Studio. I recognize it's using non-standard behavior and gave them suggestions on updating it to be more portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MSFT engineer explained the cause for this in a comment here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Out-of-range-floating-point-to-integer-c/10324943#T-ND10356428

> This happens for historical reasons, and I agree that it is not ideal. When targeting 32-bit IA, Visual Studio uses helper functions for various operations, including conversions between integer and floating-point types. In VS2017 the functions for conversion from floating-point to unsigned types are quite slow. For VS2019 we wanted to use faster functions, and the best versions available use Intel AVX-512 instructions for these conversions when possible and return the same values as those instructions when not.
>
> Until VS2019 version 16.7, MSVC did not fully define behavior for conversion of floating-point values to integer types and uses whatever machine instructions are available to implement these conversions efficiently. The 8087 floating-point coprocessor, introduced in 1980, was the base for Intel Architecture floating-point support, and it only supports conversion to signed integer types. For those types it always returns an integer indefinite value for invalid conversions. Since 8087 supports conversion to 64-bit signed integer, and the allowed values for unsigned 32-bit integers are as subset of those values, Microsoft C used conversion to signed 64-bit integer and truncation to 32 bits to convert floating-point values to 32-bit unsigned integer type.
>
> When integer type support was extended to 64-bit signed and unsigned integers, at first all 64-bit conversions were treated as signed conversions, so that floating-point values larger than the maximum 64-bit signed integer were converted to the 64-bit signed integer indefinite value `0x8000000000000000` even when the result type was unsigned, but eventually special code was added to correctly handle values `0x8000000000000000` to `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. All invalid conversions continued to be handled as conversions to signed 64-bit integer. This was the defacto behavior of integer conversions up through VS2017.
>
> VS2012 changed the default floating-point support from 8087 to SSE2, and instruction set extensions from SSE to AVX2 support only conversion to 32-bit signed integer on x86, so all other conversions must be emulated by range-checking and emulation using integer instructions. The original helper functions for these conversions did full emulation of the 8087 conversions including certain bugs that have since been fixed, but this made them much slower than the 8087 conversions, which was not ideal. In 2017, Intel launched the Skylake-X processors which support the Intel AVX-512 instruction set extensions and include instructions for converting floating point values to all 32-bit and 64-bit signed and unsigned integer types. For VS2019 we wanted to use these instructions to improve the performance of the floating-point to integer conversions.
> The AVX-512 conversions from floating-point to unsigned integer types also return integer indefinite values for all invalid conversions, but those values are different from the values for signed integers. For any integer type, the corresponding integer indefinite value is the value farthest from zero. So, for 32-bit signed integers it is `0x80000000`, and for 64-bit unsigned integers it is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. If the result is any other value, the conversion was valid. So, the AVX-512 conversions from floating-point to 32-bit unsigned integer return `0xFFFFFFFF` for invalid conversions, while the defacto VS2017 conversions can return any value.
>
> For VS2019 we should have introduced yet another new set of helper functions for conversions compatible with AVX-512 instructions and offered a command switch to select between the new functions and the prior functions, but that is not what we did. Because the behavior of the prior routines is not particularly useful and didn’t match any other MSVC target platform, we thought it would be okay to update the existing helpers with new, faster code that used AVX-512 instructions when possible and emulated them when not.
>
> Based on feedback from customers, we realized that we had made a mistake, but our options for correcting it are limited. Reverting the helper functions could change the behavior of VS2019 compiled code similarly to what you are seeing, so that is not an option. In VS2019 version 16.7 we introduced the `/fpcvt` command switch to select between VS2017-compatible behavior and AVX-512 compatible behavior, which overrides the mix of behaviors exhibited in VS2019 by the 32-bit and 64-bit IA compilers with various /arch settings. However, for x86 this only works when linking with the corresponding helper functions. In VS2022 we default back to the legacy behavior, although the `/fpcvt:IA` switch will still generate AVX-512 compatible code, and the helper functions are still compatible with VS2019.
>
> The reason VS2022 is generating additional code is that it is trying to emulate the older functionality using the new helper functions. We are adding new helper functions to emulate the older behavior directly, but for reasons I won’t go into, it takes several version updates for those changes to propagate everywhere they need to go. When those functions have propagated, we will update MSVC to directly use them and all conversions will be either generating a conversion instruction or calling the appropriate helper function.
>
> When linking VS2017 code into a VS2022 executable, the call to `__dtoul3` will go to the updated VS2022 helper function which returns the 64-bit unsigned integer indefinite value (`0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`) instead of the signed 64-bit integer value the VS2017 `__dtoul3` helper would have returned. This is expected.
>
> I do not have a specific workaround to offer you. If you need non-standard behavior, I suggest that you should use a conversion function that fully specifies what values should be returned for all argument values. This will give your code maximum portability at some cost in performance. In VS2022 there are intrinsic functions that return integer indefinite values or saturated integer values for all invalid conversion arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if linking into a 2022 executable, it breaks on the cast from double to `uint64_t`.

**Undefined behavior (UB)**

This is allowed by C.

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type ..., the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.  C17dr § 6.3.1.4 1

Only floating point values in the [-0.99999....  to 18,446,744,073,709,551,616.99999....] range are defined to convert via `(uint64_t)` as OP hoped.  Since the `3406302.4613481420 - 0.5` is ≤ -1.0, the conversion is **UB**.  [@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75869135/out-of-range-floating-point-to-integer-conversion-breaks-in-vs2022-executable-wh/75958701#comment133826400_75869135)

```
double f1 = -3406302.4613481420;
uint64_t y = (uint64_t)(f1 - 0.5);  // UB
```

---

> [I'm just curious as to why 2022 isn't compatible with 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75869135/out-of-range-floating-point-to-integer-conversion-breaks-in-vs2022-executable-wh#comment133830569_75869135).

OP's code relied on UB and so should not expect the current or prior compiler versions to act consistently.  It is not a compiler *bug*, but an OP one.

---

**Other questionable functionality**

`f1 - 0.5` is not exact with odd values less than and near 2<sup>53</sup> and so form an incorrect rounded result.

Further, other values for `do_something_2()` may not *round* as OP might hope.  To take further, the exact goal of `do_something_2()` is needed.

---

**Alternative**

Perform the modulo step with `fmod()` and a test.

```
static uint64_t do_something_2(double f1) {
    f1 = fmod(f1, 18446744073709551616.0); // remainder.
    if (f1 < 0.0) f1 += 18446744073709551616.0;
    return (uint64_t)(f1 - 0.5);
}
```

This may/may not do exactly what OP wants for all `f1` as the overall goal of `do_something_2()` remains unstated.

Comment: MSVC *does* define the behaviour of out-of-range FP to integer conversions, going beyond what the ISO standard defines.  Their blog article (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/microsoft-visual-studio-2022-and-floating-point-to-integer-conversions/) which the OP cited is about a change in that behaviour, which is probably in a library function rather than code which gets inlined, at least without AVX-512.  It seems perfectly reasonable to me to ask about a change in this implementation's extensions to ISO C.  [visual-c++] is the primary tag here, not [c].

Comment: @PeterCordes Fair enough that OP may have relied on the _compiler_ definition for what should happen with out-of-range FP to unsigned conversion.   Looks like [EEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) backfired. Had the earlier compiler simply left it as UB, OP's code original coders would have been obliged to form compliant code back then.

Comment: Microsoft responded with this reply today after I cross-posted this issue there: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Out-of-range-floating-point-to-integer-c/10324943#T-ND10356428